# Trouble with Import-SPWeb

Tags: powershell, import

Here my issue: I have 2 SP farms, therefore two web apps/site collections/ etc.

On one, I run: 
`Import-SPWeb -Identity "http://policies/locations/0015/" -Path "C:\filepath.cmp" -Force`

which works just fine. On the other farm, I run basically the same with the exception of the identity:
`Import-SPWeb -Identity "http://v2policies/locations/0015/" -Path "C:\filepath.cmp" -Force`

However this one gives the "Cannot find an SPWeb object with Id or Url" error.

Both URLs are valid, so why would one work and the other not? Running PS as admin, and the user account I am logged into is part of "SPShellAdmin". Running from CA server in each farm.

Comment: run get-spweb -identity http://v2policies/locations/0015/ and share the out put and also what if you browse this in broswer http://v2policies/locations/0015/

Comment: Running that gives the "Cannot find and SPWeb object with Id or URL" error. I am able to pull it up fine in the browser though.

Comment: it ia subsite, Site collection, list or library? try wtih get-spsite

Comment: Okay so running get-spsite returns the URL fine. So now what does that mean here? (Sorry, still fairly new to all this).

Comment: Looks like you are trying to import subsite on the a Site collection...is it right? from where u export it, did you exported a subsite or site collection?

Comment: So it's a document library that i'm trying to export and import to a specific site collection.

Comment: then this is not gonna happen at site collection level, did you exported at the same level in your source site?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much I have to export from http://policies/locations/0015 and import to http://v2policies/location/0015 which is in a different farm.

Comment: Both are the same template and did you already created the DL in advance?

Comment: Well I've gotten it to work now. It appears as if even though the account was in "SPShellAdmin" the content DB wasn't specified. Following the steps here: http://bramnuyts.be/2011/06/08/get-spweb-cannot-find-an-spweb-object-with-id-or-url/  seem to have fixed it up. Thanks for talking it out with me!

Answer (score 0):

Well I've gotten it to work now. It appears as if even though the account was in "SPShellAdmin" the content DB wasn't specified. Following the steps here: bramnuyts.be/2011/06/08/… seem to have fixed it up.